# Let’s standardise some tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Let’s standardise some tags.

For instance, there are already two competing conventions at work:

- [rna-seq](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rna-seq)
- [scrnaseq](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrnaseq)

Either both should use a dash, or none should.

I propose the slightly more readable variant: using dashes to separate *‹tech›* from “seq”. That is:

- [rna-seq](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rna-seq)
- [chip-seq](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chip-seq)
- [scrna-seq](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrna-seq)
  etc.

Comment: Totally agree, but let's see how the site evolves

Comment: While at it let's create a list of tags we should avoid using/creating.

Comment: Do you think it is OK to copy paste the tag description/info from other SE sites?

Comment: @zx8754 yes, the license definitely allows that.

Comment: Agree, but unlike @Llopis, I'm ok with a little intelligent design before evolution kicks into high gear. What's the best way to do this? Edit tags that don't conform. In other SE sites, I'm way more likely to use a tag that has a big number next to it.

Comment: @kevbonham I think we can be permitted to be more authoritative about it. Case in point, I think we can agree that [tag:scrnaseq] is a *terrible* tag, and that we should go with my suggestion.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I agree (I might not use italicized *terrible*), and I just checked, it looks like I already have the authority to change that tag. I've never been in a community at this early a stage, what's the typical etiquette for modifying other people's questions?

Comment: @kevbonham *shrug*. I’d wait a bit more but since this got +7 votes so far and nobody so far raised an object i’d just edit the tag fairly soon. That said, I think you need 500 votes to edit on your own. Otherwise it’s put up for review but barely any user can already access the review queue.

Comment: @KonradRudolph In this case, `sc-rna-seq` should probably be preferred because `xrna` usually refers to a type of RNA, not the biological system it comes from (*mRNA, tRNA, piRNA, etc.* vs. *single cell RNA* and *bulk RNA*)

Comment: @MichaelSchubert Does anybody call it "sc-RNA-seq" though? I've never seen it. It's scRNA-seq.