# Divide tags by technology and target application?

Tags: discussion, tags

Reviewing an [edit](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1162) I realized we have some duplicated tags or at least somehow redundant.

We have [scrnaseq](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrnaseq), [rna-seq](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rna-seq) and [single-cell](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-cell).

Some numbers:

- [scrnaseq](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrnaseq): [25](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrnaseq) questions
- [scrnaseq](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrnaseq) & [rna-seq](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rna-seq): [9](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rna-seq+scrnaseq)
- [rna-seq](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rna-seq) & [single-cell](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-cell): [7](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-cell+rna-seq)
- [scrnaseq](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrnaseq) & [rna-seq](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rna-seq) & [single-cell](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-cell): [1](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-cell+rna-seq+scrnaseq) (If we approve the linked edit that would be 2)

Should we remove remove [scrnaseq](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrnaseq) in favor of [rna-seq](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rna-seq) and [single-cell](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-cell)?
Or should we retag those 7 questions with both tags in favor of [scrnaseq](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrnaseq) ?

Related discussion: [Let’s standardise some tags](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/48)

As stated in the comments of the related discussion I think that the usage of these tags should differentiate between technology and target of the technology. Here [rna-seq](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rna-seq) describes a technology and [single-cell](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-cell) describes the target of a technology so it would be possible to have other technology targeting the same single cell such as metabolomics or methylation assays, or...

Answer (score 2):

I would actually be in favor of removing [single-cell](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-cell). As you pointed out, by itself, [single-cell](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-cell) isn't telling us much. It isn't enough to define a subject, it only tells us what a question is about when combined with another tag. This seems to me to fit the definition of a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/), a tag that can't stand alone and only qualifies other tags.

As a general rule, each tag should be able to stand alone. If it only makes sense when combined with another tag, then it isn't helpful.

So, I would suggest we completely remove the [single-cell](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-cell) and instead use [scrnaseq](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrnaseq). I would also suggest creating [single-cell-rnaseq](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-cell-rnaseq)
 and making [scrnseq](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrnseq) a synonym of it. I think it is best to have explicit tags where possible.  Having this synonym would mean that when someone tags with [scrnaseq](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrnaseq), the question would be tagged with [single-cell-rnaseq](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-cell-rnaseq) instead, but you could still search for [scrnaseq](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrnaseq) and find the relevant questions.

Then, if and when we start getting questions about other single-cell targeting technologies, we can create tags for them.

Comment: I would argue that single-cell as pointed by Devon is used for questions about peculiarities and problems associated with that kind of analysis. See for example this [question](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/3004/) that used "scATAC-seq".

Comment: @Llopis are there any issues that are specific to single cell experiments as opposed to *this type* of single cell experiments? Can someone be an expert in "single cell" in general? If the answer is no (I think it is no, but I don't really know much about this), then the tag isn't helpful. Think of tags as a way of directing experts to the questions they are interested in, as well as a general way of categorizing. If there really are problems shared by all single-cell approaches, then maybe the tag is useful, but if not, let's replace it with more specific ones.

Comment: I don't know much about single cell experiments just what I learned here. But I see that they have a common problems, like the large sparsity, (batch effects ?), and mechanical problems that affect the analysis.

Comment: @Llopis OK, if there really are similar enough that someone could be an expert in "single-cells", then the tag might make sense.

Comment: Maybe we can wait a little to know what problems do people have before judging. I'm sure we'll get more question in those kind of analysis

Comment: Why not change `single-cell` to `single-cell-sequencing` then? I suspect that other sc-seq methods are going to present a lot of the same issues that scrnaseq do

Answer (score 1):

I would propose adding [scrnaseq](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrnaseq) to the 7 [rna-seq](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rna-seq) & [single-cell](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-cell) posts. scRNA-seq is a popular enough method in its own right with peculiarities that it warrants its own tag, in my opinion.